# Disproving unique factorization of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

For homework, we were given a problem that asked to explain why $(\sqrt{-6})(-\sqrt{-6})$ implies $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$ does not have a unique factorization.

I understand the unique part in this case only means unique up to multiplication by a unit, but how does $(\sqrt{-6})(-\sqrt{-6})$ relate to that? Is it that each of the square roots can be factored in more than one way?

Comment: Hi Mark! It means that for at least one $x \in \Bbb Q[\sqrt-6]$, this number $x$ can be written in two differents ways in terms of irreducible elements of the ring. Can you guess which number and which irreducibles work for this counterexample?

Comment: Hello, Leo! Could it be $-2$ and $3$, for example? A prime factorization of $-6$?

Comment: So that's two irreducibles (why?) and which are the other two?

Comment: $2$ and $-3$ (i.e. the other possibility)? Are they irreducible because if they are prime in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$? Since they divide $\sqrt{-6}$?

Comment: Sorry, it's late here and I'm tired but I was talking as if it was $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ as that is a domain. Otherwise when we are dealing with $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{-6}]$ note that it is a field so checking if it is a UFD it's a rather vacuous affair.

Comment: So, what were the other two numbers? Thanks for your help so far, by the way.

Comment: Did you get what my last messagge said? That as the problem is stated there's no need to check for this examples as it's a field. Now if you want to solve the problem for $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ use for this domain the clue that you were given :p

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
10=2\cdot 5=(2-\sqrt{-6})(2+\sqrt{-6}).
$$
Now show that these elements are irreducible in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$, so that this
ring is not a UFD.